# Oozie Hive Logs Missing

Tags: java, hive, oozie

I have oozie hive action. After some failure, I see only the exit code of hive script in the oozie logs(Oozie web console/Job Log screen) not the cause of the error in words.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below link can solve your problem ...

http://www.hadoopinrealworld.com/troubleshooting-hive-action-in-oozie/